# How to send an entire Entity Framework Core context from server to client

Tags: performance, serialization, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core server application that uses Entity Framework Core to provide data of its SQL server.

There are clients that can consume the data via REST API calls.

At the beginning of the communication, it is required to have all the data on the clients but using the existing REST calls it takes *minutes* as the context contains thousands of entities.

So I looked for ideas and tried the following.

The best looking idea was some kind of serializing, so I created the following method:

```
public byte[] GetData()
{
   string data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.ChangeTracker, 
                 new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings {
                 ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
   return CompressAsGZip(data);
}
```

The results:

- Serializing (and then compressing) the `ChangeTracker` of the context

  - Initially the `ChangeTracker` is empty so I can't do it unless I query all the data
- Serializing (and then compressing) the entire DbContext

  - It has so many objects that after 20%, I got an *OutOfMemoryException*

Should I create a database backup and send the compressed bak file? I guess I couldn't restore it to anywhere as the client database provider is different (*SQLite*).

What would be the best way to send all the data to the client as fast as it can be?

Comment: Send a database backup. Context/ChangeTracker shouldn't be serialized. Even if it were possible, what do you imagine the receiver should do with the deserialized object?

Comment: @GertArnold On the client side there is no infrastructure to restore the database (at is has a different database provider (SQLite)). Did you mean some other way?

Comment: Actually, I don't understand the problem. Somehow you're going to have to wire data. That will take time irrespective of how you're going to offer it. Is a couple of minutes really such a big deal? Also, the API is the primary communication channel. It ensures well-shaped data and data integrity. A second communication channel should do all that again.

Comment: @GertArnold Okay, but as a first approach, I need something faster. Some kind of binary, compressed, one batch download of the data, that is restored on the client and then only the changes are sent again. Say, that the first approach is a compressed backup (say 10 MB), and it is downloaded in one request. Is it faster than having approx. 500 API queries?